# Java: Set back the same JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

When I open a new JFrame, I set the old one as false:

```
ExampleJFrame.this.setVisible(false);
ExampleNewJframe newOne = ExampleNewJframe();
newOne.setVisible(true);
```

But If I am in newOne, how do I get back to the original Frame without creating a new as I did above?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution: don't go swapping JFrames; that's can be a rough design that can annoy users. Instead swap JPanel "views" using a CardLayout as per [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice).